# What is a short term for person agreeing and later disagreeing

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, phrase-requests, terminology

What is some one called when the person agrees to anything mindlessly early on and then realized that those agreed beliefs are against one own and start to disagree ?

Comment: the person had second thoughts, changed his mind

Comment: What part of speech do you want?  Also, please supply a sample sentence to show how you'd like to use the word.  In addition, please narrow the field (which is fairly wide) by providing some context, and letting us know what sort of tone you're aiming for.  I voted to close as unclear what you're asking, but if you can clarify, I'm happy to vote to reopen.  (Notify me after you edit, please -- thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

Your post is not clear, but... *Reneger* might work, meaning 'someone who reneges or has reneged.' (Link to [reneger](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/reneger) at Oxford dictionary, to show it exists and for looking at examples, although you might want to click through to 'renege': *Go back on a promise, undertaking, or contract*).

Comment: Flip-flopper? Space cadet?

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you probably want is ***fickle*** (adj). however it is its more modern sense (2 in the OED) that applies in this case. Originally it meant *false, deceitful, or treacherous*, but the OED has no examples of that since the fifteenth century.

The modern meaning is:

> 2. Changeable, changeful, inconstant, uncertain, unreliable:
>
>    a. of persons, their attributes, feelings, etc.; also often, with
>      personification, of Fortune, Chance, etc.

There are examples from the thirteenth century:

> a1275   Prov. Ælfred 355 in Old Eng. Misc. (1872) 125   For moni mon
>   hauit fikil mod.
>
> ?1550   J. Bale Apol. agaynste Papyst Pref. 12 b,   I maruile What
>   hath moued the fyckle heades of our doctours.
>
> 1599   Shakespeare Romeo & Juliet iii. v. 60   O Fortune, Fortune, all
>   men call thee fickle .
>
> 1629   W. Prynne Church of Englands Old Antithesis 78   It makes the
>   fickle, wauering, and vnconstant will of man, the very basis.
>
> 1663   A. Cowley Agriculture in Wks. (1710) II. 708   An impudent,
>   fickle, and painted Harlot.
>
> 1667   Milton Paradise Lost ii. 233   When everlasting Fate shall
>   yield To fickle  Chance.
>
> 1783   W. Thomson in R. Watson & W. Thomson Hist. Reign Philip III vi.
>   416   Though sovereign princes..be naturally capricious and fickle in
>   their attachments.
>
> 1815   Scott Lord of Isles vi. vi. 229   Versed in the fickle heart of
>   man.
>
> 1861   J. G. Holland Lessons in Life iii. 44   Friends may prove
>   false, and fortune fickle.
>
> 1870   W. C. Bryant tr. Homer Iliad I. iii. 85   The younger men are
>   of a fickle mood.